# Laplace transform of $f(t)=\frac{\sin(t)}t$ for $t>0$, $f(t)=0$ for $t \le 0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, laplace-transform

Determine Laplace transform of $$f(t)=\begin{cases} \frac{\sin(t)}{t} \qquad t>0 \\ \\ 0 \qquad \ \ \ \ \ \ \ t  \le 0 \end{cases}$$

I know Laplace transform of $\frac{\sin(t)}{t}$ is $F(s)=\arctan(\frac{1}{s})$ (from another topic on this forum)

The Laplace transform of $$g(t)=\begin{cases} f(t-a) \qquad t \ge a \\ 0 \qquad \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  t<a  \end{cases}$$ is $$G(s)=F(s) \ e^{-sa}$$

How can I determine the Laplace transform considering the different conditions on $t$ ?

Thanks!

Comment: $G(s) = \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(t)}{t} e^{-st}dt, G'(s) = -\int_0^\infty \sin(t) e^{-st}dt = \frac{1}{2i}(\frac{1}{s+i}-\frac{1}{s-i})$, $G(s) = C+\int G'(s)ds = C+ \frac{1}{2i}(\log(s+i)-\log(s-i))$, $\int_a^\infty \frac{\sin(t-a)}{t-a} e^{-st}dt = e^{-sa} G(s)$

Comment: @user1952009 Nice. Why not make it an answer?

Comment: @user1952009 you cna fix the constant by observing that $G(0)=\frac{\pi}2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) we have:
The Laplace transform of a function $f(t)$, defined for all real numbers $t \ge 0$,
is the function $F(s)$, which is a *unilateral transform* [ emphasis by us ]
defined by
$$
F(s) = \int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-st}\,dt
$$
The unilateral transform ($t \ge 0$) of the sine is (table @ Wikipedia):
$$
\sin(\omega t)\cdot u(t) \; \to \; \frac{\omega}{s^2+\omega^2}
\quad \Longrightarrow \quad
\sin(t)\cdot u(t) \; \to \; \frac{1}{1+s^2}
$$
Where the Heaviside step function $u(t)$ is defined by:
$$
u(t) =
\begin{cases} 0 & \mbox{for} & t < 0\\ 1 & \mbox{for} & t \ge 0\end{cases}
$$
The unilateral transform ($t \ge 0$) of a function $f(t)/t$ is (table @ Wikipedia):
$$
\frac{1}{t}f(t) \; \to \; \int_s^\infty F(\sigma)\,d\sigma
$$
Combining these:
$$
f(t) = \frac{\sin(t)}{t}\cdot u(t) \; \to \; \int_s^\infty \frac{d\sigma}{1+\sigma^2} =
\left[\arctan(\sigma)\right]_s^\infty = \frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan(s) = F(s)
$$
Forget about the rule $\;G(s)=F(s) \ e^{-sa}\;$, because for $\,a=0\,$ it adds nothing new here : $G(s)=F(s) \ e^{-s0} = F(s)$ .